# R Proportion on weighted Kaplan Meier curve vs Proportion with svymean function

Tags: r, curve

I am plotting a Kaplan Meier curve for the ROR vaccinate coverage (VC) rate of children from 6m to 17y with a survey design object (RORpps). Here is my code :

```
fit <- svykm(Surv(dROR2, ROR2) ~ 1, design = RORpps, se =  T)
svyjskm(fit, ci = F, cumhaz = T, ylims = c(0, 0.8), xlims = c(0, 13), 
  ystrataname = "", timeby = 1, showpercent = T, ylab = "VC rate (%)", 
  xlab = "Age", surv.scale = "percent", pval = T, table = F, pval.testname = T)
```

The percentage of the plot indicate a coverage rate of 71,1% while with the svymean function

```
svymean(~ ROR2, RORpps, na.rm = TRUE)
```

I get 70,1%. Why this difference? Shouldn't it be the same? Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'm the developer of [jskm](https://github.com/jinseob2kim/jskm) package.

The proportion calculated by **svymean** does not consider time(**dPOR2**), so it is different from the kaplan-meier estimate.

Comment: Indeeed, time is not considered. Thanks for your answer!